# Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

Application Stack

- Jenkins
- .NET 4.7
- SonarQube 7.4
- Bitbucket (Source control)
- VS 2015 Update 3
- VsTest to execute UnitTest

Path of Msbuid in Global Tools Configuration is

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Msbuild.exe
2. Also tried with C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Msbuild.exe

We have created sample project and configured all in one server.

We can see multiple kind of errors in log files like

- Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
- WARNING: File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CICD\UnitTestProject1\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' is not located under the root directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CICD.sonarqube\out' and will not be analyzed
- No analysable projects were found. SonarQube analysis will not be performed
- **This only comes when i use msbuild from "Program files"** An instance of analyzer SonarAnalyzer.Rules.CSharp.FieldsShouldNotBePublic cannot be created from C:\Users\manish.joisar\AppData\Local\Temp.sonarqube\resources\0\SonarAnalyzer.CSharp.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

I can see message with build succeeded.

I can also see successful test run message
Total tests: 1. Passed: 1. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Successful.

Sonar configuration is done in build configuration under "Execute Sonar scanner" step

I am not sure what is missing here, wrong configuration, wrong msbuild ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved all above issues with below configuration in Jenkins

**SonarQube configuration**
[image]

**Jenkin Global tool configuration**
[image]

**Freestyle project configuration**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have gone through this documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild for getting all the dependencies information and the command required to run the analysis.

I was getting some of the error mentioned above when i was trying to analyse c# files but i require more information to understand your case so please provide the o/p of each steps mentioned below:

```
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"project-key"
MSBuild.exe <path to solution.sln> /t:Rebuild
SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

If you are running through jenkins MSBuild plugin, then please provide the verbose output of the same.